# Swift: possible removeObserver cyclic reference in addObserverForName's usingBlock

Tags: swift, nsnotification

I'm toying around with a small Swift application. In it the user can create as many *MainWindow* instances as he wants by clicking on "New" in the application's menu.

The application delegate holds an array typed to *MainWindowController*. The windows are watched for the *NSWindowWillCloseNotification* in order to remove the controller from the *MainWindowController* array.

The question now is, if the removal of the observer is done correctly – I fear there might be a cyclic reference to *observer*, but I don't know how to test for that:

```
class ApplicationDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

  private let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
  private var mainWindowControllers = [MainWindowController]()

  func newWindow() {
    let mainWindowController = MainWindowController()
    let window = mainWindowController.window
    var observer: AnyObject?
    observer = notificationCenter.addObserverForName(NSWindowWillCloseNotification, 
                                                     object: window,
                                                     queue: nil) { (_) in
            // remove the controller from self.mainWindowControllers
            self.mainWindowControllers = self.mainWindowControllers.filter() {
              $0 !== mainWindowController
            }
            // remove the observer for this mainWindowController.window
            self.notificationCenter.removeObserver(observer!)
    }
    mainWindowControllers.append(mainWindowController)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you should always specify that `self` is unowned in blocks registered with `NSNotificationCenter`.  This will keep the block from having a strong reference to `self`.  You would do this with a capture list in front of the parameter list of your closure:

```
{ [unowned self] (_) in
    // Block content
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this tipp. My question actually was how to test if there is a cyclic reference, but I must say I phrased it not specific enough – my bad.

I found a way to test that by filtering out the lines with _NSWindowWillCloseNotification_ in _notificationCenter.debugDescription_.